# WordPress Menu Not Showing Up

Tags: php, wordpress, menu, themes

I am developing a bespoke WordPress Theme for a client and I cannot get the WP Menu to show up on any page (including the Home) and posts!

On the admin backend under **apperance > menus** it works perfectly!
I am also using the exact same wp_menu array I have used in all of my themes. Here is the code in my header.php file

```
<div id="menu">
    <nav class="top-links" role="navigation">
        <?php
            wp_nav_menu(array(
                'menu'              => 'primary',
                'theme_location'    => 'primary',
                'depth'             => 2,
                'container'         => 'div',
                'container_class'   => 'top-links-nav',
                'fallback_cb'       => 'wp_bootstrap_navwalker::fallback',
                'walker'            => new wp_bootstrap_navwalker())
            );
        ?>
    </nav>
</div>
```

and here is the code in the function.php file...

```
/* Register the Nav Menu */
function register_my_menus() { 
    require_once('wp_bootstrap_navwalker.php');
    register_nav_menus(array( 
        'primary' => _( 'Primary Menu' ), 
        'header-top-menu' => _( 'Header Top Menu' ) 
    )); 
    } 
add_action( 'init', 'register_my_menus' ); 
/* End the Nav Menu */
```

I am using version 4.1.1 of WordPress and I have cot all my files commented correctly! I know this code does work so have no idea why it's not on this!

Comment: In the menu settings have checked the option 'Theme locations'? Primary? (Simple I know but worth a check). Have you got your error reporting on with wp_debug any errors?

Comment: @David.J Yep was one of the first things I checked! I just turned on the WP Debug and no errors are showing up buddy.

Comment: Nothing is showing up in firebug as well! I have tested it in all browsers including IE and still no Joy there! been like this 2 days now!

Comment: Could we do a reduced test with this: `       <?php if ( has_nav_menu( 'primary' ) ) {  ?>
        
        <?php wp_nav_menu( array( 
         'container' => 'div', 
         'container_class' => 'top-links-na', 
         'theme_location' => 'primary' 
        ) ); ?>
       
       <?php } else { ?>
       
        <h1>No Primary Menu</h1>
        
       <?php }  ?>`

Comment: Cool. I'll post that as an answer.

Comment: If one of these answers did help you resolve this issue, please consider marking an answer as correct. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

A reduced test case should get you started:

```
<?php if ( has_nav_menu( 'primary' ) ) { ?>
    <?php wp_nav_menu( array( 
        'container' => 'div', 
        'container_class' => 'top-links-nav', 
        'theme_location' => 'primary' ) ); 
    ?> 
<?php } else { ?> 
    <h1>No Primary Menu</h1> 
<?php } ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try changing the `init` action to `after_setup_theme`:

```
add_action('after_setup_theme', 'register_my_menus');
```